# How to pronounce chapter 1?

Tags: american-english

It seems like the "1" in "Chapter 1" is an ordinal number, while people always pronounce it as "chapter one" instead of "chatper first", how come?

Comment: Wouldn't "chapter first" be written "Chapter 1st," not "Chapter 1"?

Comment: "Chapter 1" pronounced "Chapter first" ... In some languages it is done this way.  But not in English.

Comment: It's the same with pages ("page one"), books/volumes, acts and scenes, and other divisions, although more playful writers like Lewis Carroll sometimes deviated.

Comment: It used to be "Chapter the First" as a post-positive adjective: see the chapter lists on the left of https://www.oxfordscholarlyeditions.com/display/10.1093/actrade/9780198124931.book.1/actrade-9780198124931-div2-5

Comment: Yes: we'd never say 'Henry eight' for Henry VIII. But on the other hand, we label lists (whether laid out expressly as such, or notional as with chapters, diagrams) using letters too. Would we speak of 'the bth diagram' for 'diagram b'?  This is a matter only addressable by a descriptive stance (what people actually do, however illogical / contradictory) rather than a prescriptive one (logic demands that an ordinal number be used).

Comment: The phrase "The first chapter" is often used but it is a separate phrase not an alternative to reading "Chapter 1" as "Chapter one". If we intended to use an ordinal number it would be written like that. As @AndrewLeach says in his comment the term "Chapter **the** first" (not chapter first) used to be used but is now archaic.